# How do I prove the formula of the general term(with induction) of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n}+6}{2} ,a_{1}=1 , a_{2}=3$

That is the formula for the recursive form of the sequence,I found the general term formula for the sequence(the sequence was $1,3,5,7,....$) ,the formula is $a_{n}=2n-1$.So the statement for the induction is $P_{(n)}: a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n}+6}{2}=2(n+2)-1$ so I tried to do with $P_{(k)}$ and with $P_{(k+1)}$ but i did not get anywere so I tried to say that for any even number the statement is true,so from that I said that $P_{(2k)}$ is true ,from it I got that $a_{(2k+1)}=4(2k+4)-2-a_{2k}-6$ knowing that for any even number the statement is true we can calculate $a_{(2k)}=2(2k+2)-1=4k+3$ ,from that I plugged it in $a_{2k+1}$ and got $a_{2k+1}=4k+5$ so I did the formula for $a_{2k+1}$ and got it true,so the formula is good.Am I wrong?(was I supposed to do it for $P_{(2k+1)}$,as well?)

Comment: One approach is, first show it's true for $n=1$, and $n=2$, and then show that if it's true for $k$ and $k+1$, then it's true for $k+2$.

Comment: I did that but the problem is that i do not know $a_{k}$ and $a_{k+1}$ so when I do it I get a lot more $a_{k+....}$ so I did it for $2k$ and $2k+1$(I assumed that the statement is true for any even number)

Comment: Have you not done any proofs by induction before? You are trying to prove $a_n=2n-1$, right? So, you prove it's true for $1$ and $2$, and then you prove that IF that formula holds for $k$ and $k+1$, THEN it holds for $k+2$.

Comment: Yes,I did do with proofs with induction before,and if you have read what i said above you can see that I did do for k and k+1 and did not work

Comment: In that case, your formula $a_n=2n-1$ is wrong, or your formulas for $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ are wrong, or your algebra for finding $a_{k+2}$ is wrong, or else you have proved that mathematics is inconsistent, in which case we can all go do something else. So I'd suggest you check your work, thoroughly.

Comment: With the given seed, each iteration you're essentially taking $1$ step back($b_{n+2} = (a_{n+2} + a_{n+1})/2$) and $3$ steps forward($a_{n+2} = b_{n+2}+3$). so the next term is always $2$ steps ahead and the solution is of form $a(n) = 2n + c$

Answer (score 1):

The base case is clear.

Now assume that $n \in \mathbb N$ and

$(*) \quad a_k=2k-1$ for $k=1,2,...,n.$

It follows that $a_{n+1}= \frac{a_n+a_{n-1}+6}{2}.$

From $(*)$ we get $a_n=2n-1$ and $a_{n-1}=2n-3.$

Now show that $a_{n+1}= \frac{a_n+a_{n-1}+6}{2}=2(n+1)-1.$